# Select records starting with first character and there after all records

Tags: mysql

Following is the data

```
Name         Age
-------  ----------------
Alan        23
James       24
Amy         41
Brian       42
Jacob       44
```

If I enter "B" then all the records starting from "B" and other those are greater than "B" should get displayed. Required output

```
Name         Age
-------  ----------------
Jacob       44
James       24
Brian       42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `>` or `>=` (if you'll ever have a name of B that you want returning) you'll get what you want; strings sort such that "no character at this position" is sooner in an A-Z list than "any character". This means that `B` (with no character at position 2) is sooner in an A-Z than `Ba` (with `a` at position 2) so in effect you're looking for all strings greater than your prefix

```
Andy      --excluded: A... is less than B
Barney    --included: Ba... is greater than B
Charlie   --included: C... is greater than B
```